# Pipe Delimited Output from Query and not Settings?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am writing an SSIS package to handle the output from a SQL query and my intent is to have SQL/SSMS generate a pipe delimited file. I understand that normally this can be achieved with the below SSMS setting specifications:

```
Tools--> Options --> Query Results --> Sql Server --> Results to Text. Change output format from Tab Delimited to Custom Delimited. Put a Pipe in the Custom Delimiter Box. Go back to your query select Query --> Results to File. Execute file, Give it a Disk path and a name.
```

As I'm trying to automate this via SSIS what I am trying to do instead if find if it's possible to specify pipe delimited columns in my file via the SQL query directly. Is this possible? I've found a few 'workarounds' to reproduce this but none of them have seemed all that graceful. Thank you.

Comment: You can specify the delimiter in the [Flat File Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver16). Are you looking for something different from that?  The setting you mentioned in your question is from SSMS, which is a tool -- it is not SQL Server itself.  SQL Server itself doesn't know about flat file or result delimiters.

Comment: Hi Devlin, I'm looking to see if it's possible to have the output from the SQL query itself yield a pipe delimited format

Comment: MS SQL does not have a built-in function for delimiting results.

Comment: I believe that answers my question then, thank you devlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected production of a pipe delimited file from SQL query is not natively supported with a built in delimiter option, per Devlin Carnate.

Solutions for such queries can be achieved via a number of different ways including SSIS connection manager details as well as fancier SQL queries that are, inevitably, workarounds options.